# How to get php messages in order

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a private message board but when I logged in as the other user it move all the messages to the front which you have just posted. How can I keep messages in the same order?

Please find below the code:

```
    $grab_messages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pvt_messages WHERE user_to='$username' && user_from='$user' && opened='no'");
$numrows_read = mysql_numrows($grab_messages);
if ($numrows_read != 0) {
while ($get_msg = mysql_fetch_assoc($grab_messages)) {
      $id = $get_msg['id']; 
      $user_from = $get_msg['user_from'];
      $user_to = $get_msg['user_to'];
      $msg_body = $get_msg['msg_body'];
      $date = $get_msg['date'];
      $opened = $get_msg['opened']; 

      $check_pic = mysql_query("SELECT profile_pic FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
$get_pic_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_pic);
$profile_pic_db = $get_pic_row['profile_pic'];
if ($profile_pic_db == "") {
 $profile_pic = "../img/QNdefualt.jpg";
}
else
{
 $profile_pic = "$profile_pic_db";
}
    ?>
    <li class="self">
        <div class="avatar"><img src="<?php echo $profile_pic; ?>" draggable="false"/></div>
      <div class="msg">
        <p><?php echo $msg_body; ?></p>
        <time><?php echo $date; ?></time>
      </div>
    </li>
```

- Main part of code

Comment: `order by \`date\``

Comment: what is "in order"?

Comment: In order from who posted their message first and wouldn't ordered by date not work cause it only counts days months and years and not seconds

Comment: then add a time column and sort by that also!?

Comment: @EthanThompson Use a `datetime` or `timestamp` datatype. That has the time down to the second.

Comment: I made a time stamp and I am still having trouble getting it to put messages in order.

Comment: When you added the time stamp, on the existing rows, did you populate the hh:mm:ss values or did you just leave them blank?  If you didn't load them, they probably all have midnight as a value.  So, your ORDER BY datetimefield still wouldn't have any effect.  You have to make sure you're putting the time values in.

Comment: Use a sequence counter, like a AUTOINCREMENT column, then the storage in the table produces an unique number, where you can order by. see [mysql-Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)